# Is there any way to pass Context into HtmlHelper extension?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im working on my new Helper, which extended from HtmlHelper.

In my method, i need to call out data from Context. The context can be called from the View, but is there anyway i can just call it in HtmlHelper?

The application is writen in ASP.net MVC 2.0 RC2.

Thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext
```

Comment: perfect. I dont' know it was there :P Thanks!